# Weird conversion from list to dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a list that I created from a for loop and it looks like this:
[image]

I tried to convert it to a dataframe using the code:

```
dflist<- as.data.frame(mylist)
```

But my dataframe looks like this now:
[image]

I know I probably created my list wrong but I am thinking this is still salvageable if I just need to convert the numbers to a dataframe correctly.

**My end goal** is to plot the numbers against their index (1-30) and I thought creating a dataframe first to clean it up and then plot would be helpful.
Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For future questions: Do not post your data as an image, but learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easiers for other to help you.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to reproduce what I did without posting a long bit of code plus attaching a dataset.

Comment: In this case `dput(head(mylist, 10))` and `dflist[, 1:5]` would have been sufficient to explain your problem. This is also explained in the linked Q&A. HTH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data showed is a `list`. We can use `unlist` and create a `data.frame`.  Based on the image showed in OP's post, each `list` element have a `length` of 1.  By doing `unlist`, we convert the `list` to `vector` and then wrap with `data.frame`.

```
data.frame(ind= seq_along(lst), Col1= as.numeric(unlist(lst)))
```

---

Or another option would be `stack` after naming the `list` elements

```
df1 <- transform(stack(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst))),
                 values = as.numeric(values))
```

It gives a two column dataset.  From this we can do the `plot`ting

---

Regarding the OP's approach about calling `as.data.frame` directly on the `list`, it does work in a different way as it calls on `as.data.frame.list`.  For example, if we do `as.data.frame` on a `vector`, it uses `as.data.frame.vector`

```
as.data.frame(1:5)
# 1:5
#1   1
#2   2
#3   3
#4   4
#5   5
```

But, if we call `as.data.frame.list`

```
as.data.frame.list(1:5)
#  X1L X2L X3L X4L X5L
#1   1   2   3   4   5
```

we get a data.frame with 'n' columns (based on the length of the vector).

Suppose, we do the same on a `list`

```
as.data.frame(as.list(1:5))
#  X1L X2L X3L X4L X5L
#1   1   2   3   4   5
```

It uses the `as.data.frame.list`.  To get the complete list of `methods` of `as.data.frame`,

```
methods('as.data.frame')
#[1] as.data.frame.aovproj*        as.data.frame.array          
# [3] as.data.frame.AsIs            as.data.frame.character      
# [5] as.data.frame.chron*          as.data.frame.complex        
# [7] as.data.frame.data.frame      as.data.frame.data.table*    
# [9] as.data.frame.Date            as.data.frame.dates*         
#[11] as.data.frame.default         as.data.frame.difftime       
#[13] as.data.frame.factor          as.data.frame.ftable*        
#[15] as.data.frame.function*       as.data.frame.grouped_df*    
#[17] as.data.frame.idf*            as.data.frame.integer        
#[19] as.data.frame.ITime*          as.data.frame.list      <-------     
#[21] as.data.frame.logical         as.data.frame.logLik*        
#[23] as.data.frame.matrix          as.data.frame.model.matrix   
#[25] as.data.frame.noquote         as.data.frame.numeric        
#[27] as.data.frame.numeric_version as.data.frame.ordered        
#[29] as.data.frame.POSIXct         as.data.frame.POSIXlt        
#[31] as.data.frame.raw             as.data.frame.rowwise_df*    
#[33] as.data.frame.table           as.data.frame.tbl_cube*      
#[35] as.data.frame.tbl_df*         as.data.frame.tbl_dt*        
#[37] as.data.frame.tbl_sql*        as.data.frame.times*         
#[39] as.data.frame.ts              as.data.frame.vector
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the second option involving stack and it worked as I needed it to. Very thorough explanation!